# How to add Google Tag Manager code in Prestashop without a module

Tags: php, prestashop

I use Prestashop version 1.6.1.24 for my website and I would like to add Google Tag Manager code in it. All the solutions I have found are either partial or they use a paid module.

Is there a way to add GTM code in Prestashop without using a module ?

Answer (score 2):

Search for your head.tpl file.
In the default "custom" theme, the file is located at `themes/classic/templates/_partials/head.tpl`

Insert the code snippet. I recommend inserting before the {block name='header_charset'} tag, inside the smarty "literal" tag.

```
{literal} 
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=your_tgm_id"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'your_tgm_id');
    </script>  
    {/literal}



{block name='head_charset'}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
{/block}
```

Or here is a free Google Tag Manager module for PrestaShop
https://github.com/MSiliunas/Prestashop-GoogleTagManager

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in file **templates/_partials/head.tpl**,
Edit that file and paste in your HTML-snippet of your Google Tag Manager

Comment: There is no file path templates/_partials in the version that I use.

Comment: @JorgeParasol, do you have any "head.tpl"?

Answer (score 0):

Good day.
I've struck on this topic for a while.
The main problem is that GTM needs at least its snippet of code injected in the head section of the Prestashop page.
This could be done by editing the `head.tpl` file, the location of this file depends on the theme you are using, so, probably is better if you dig in this problem before proceed.

After you found the `head.tpl`, you need to insert the GTM code in it, as a tpl,  you cannot use symbols like "{" in it without the {literal} tag (take a look at smarty if you don't know what I'm talking about).
By the way, the code to insert in the file is like this:

```
{literal}
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','XXX-XXXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
 {/literal}
```

Ok, now you have TGM loeaded in the site, but it will do nothing more than stay there and looking at you.
This is where I strucked for months.
I've got one side that says that you can "do whatever you want into TAG MANAGER without call the websites developers to insert some code some where", this is true, because TGM gives you tons of things to do within it (custom HTML let you write your own javascript, for example), but the forkflow of doing the eventlistener for every site I like to track and the creation of a consistent datalayer for it, going down in the page to find where the price is written and take it from javascript injected by TGM, seems to be a lot difficult, full of error possibilites and a madness to debug some months after you do it.

On the other hand, there are a lot of Prestashop modules that build the desired dataLayer on the website, but all of them aren't free, and they push you torward the problem "what's happen if the developers of this module abandon it"?

Actually I'm trying to "build" a set of tags and variables in GTM, usable in each e-commerce project, I'm looking also at TGM templates to makes them more portable, but the effort is very high, and on most of my websites I still have some kind of module that makes the TGM JOB on that side.